# Can I recover the keyring from a backup?

Tags: password, seahorse

I always keep `/home` as a separate partition during (re)installs of Ubuntu, so all my settings are kept. Now I don't know if it happened right after installing a fresh copy of the new Ubuntu version, or after changing my password, but all my keyring passwords are gone. Even though my entire home is kept.

What are reasons for the keyring to be reset? Does Ubuntu store backups of the keyring somewhere? Is it possible for me to get the old `~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring` from a disk image? Or is there no way to access the passwords after I changed the password for my main user?

Because I remember the old password, but if the login keyring works with a salted hash, I'm probably at a dead end, right?

There are some important entries in there that I didn't backup anywhere else.